How to integrate CEF application with Jmeter for performance testing
I have automated CEF application with Selenium. Now I need to add performance testing of same application with Jemeter, How to do the same. Please find driver option below for Selenium
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("C:/Apps/DAM/DAM.exe");
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

I did not find anything about CEF integration with JMeter. I found something like this

Open JMeter and go to Test Plan.

Right-click Test Plan, then select Add → Non-Test Elements → HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder.

This creates a proxy server in JMeter that will capture traffic.


Step 2: Configure JMeter's Proxy

In the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder configuration:

Set the Port to something like 8888 (or any available port).

In the Target Controller, select where the recorded requests will be saved, such as a Thread Group.

Set the Capture HTTP Headers checkbox to record headers.

Leave other settings as default for now.




Step 3: Configure CEF Application to Use JMeter's Proxy

The CEF application needs to use JMeter's proxy to send its HTTP traffic through it. Here’s how you might configure this:

Modify CEF's proxy settings: Depending on how your CEF app is designed, it may have a configuration file or command-line options to set a proxy.

Set the proxy server to point to localhost:8888 (or whatever port you configured JMeter to listen on).

Ensure the application is sending all HTTP(S) traffic through JMeter.



If you're not sure how to set the proxy for your CEF application, check with the developers or refer to the CEF documentation.



You're setting the proxy in an incorrect place, if you want to convert your Selenium scripts into a JMeter test plan you should set the proxy for Selenium WebDriver, something like:
org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy()
proxy.setHttpProxy("localhost:8888")
proxy.setSslProxy("localhost:8888")

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("C:/Apps/DAM/DAM.exe");
options.setProxy(proxy)
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

Another (easier) option could be using Proxy2JMX Converter tool of Taurus framework
